# Compiling errors when using ros.h in Unreal

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am totally new to ROS and I am trying to make this tutorial happen in Unreal Engine(4.14):
http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Receiving%20Messages

However, I got a lot of errors when I tried to compile ros.h in Unreal. I am using VS2015.

Please let me know if you know what happened. Thanks in advance!

The error log is followed:

Error   C2575   'deserialize': only member functions and bases can be virtual   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   43
Error   C2660   'memcpy': function does not take 2 arguments    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   37
Error   C3646   'req_param_resp': unknown override specifier    TrafficProject  d:\unreal projects\trafficproject\source\ros_lib\ros\node_handle.h  490
Error   C2448   'rosserial_msgs::msg': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   26
Error   C2270   'serialize': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   30
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   32
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   33
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   34
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   37
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   45
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   46
Error   C2355   'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   54
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\RequestParam.h  9
Error       Failed to produce item: D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-TrafficProject-4209.dll  TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ERROR   1
Error   C2227   left of '->level' must point to class/struct/union/generic type TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   32
Error   C2227   left of '->level' must point to class/struct/union/generic type TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   33
Error   C2227   left of '->level' must point to class/struct/union/generic type TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   45
Error   C2227   left of '->level' must point to class/struct/union/generic type TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   46
Error   C2227   left of '->msg' must point to class/struct/union/generic type   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   34
Error   C2227   left of '->msg' must point to class/struct/union/generic type   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   37
Error   C2227   left of '->msg' must point to class/struct/union/generic type   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   54
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   24
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   25
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    TrafficProject  d:\unreal projects\trafficproject\source\ros_lib\ros\node_handle.h  490
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   23
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'constant'    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   20
Error   C2059   syntax error: '}'   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   64
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\RequestParam.h  9
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   20
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   64
Error   MSB3073 The command ""D:\Unreal Engine\UE_4.14\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Rebuild.bat" TrafficProjectEditor Win64 Development "D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\TrafficProject.uproject" -waitmutex" exited with code -1. TrafficProject  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   46
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   TrafficProject  D:\Unreal Projects\TrafficProject\Source\ros_lib\rosserial_msgs\Log.h   20

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263190/compiling-errors-when-using-ros.h-in-unreal/) by [116Exia](https://answers.ros.org/users/30642/116exia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I figured it out: It is the def conflict of "ERROR" between log.h and wingdi.h. I just undef the "ERROR" in log.h and it works fine.

---

Originally posted by [116Exia](https://answers.ros.org/users/30642/116exia/) with karma: 16 on 2017-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0